# Подключение авторизации через фейсбук к джанго

Tags: django, facebook, oauth2, аутентификация

Пытался подключить авторизацию через фейсбук к сайту на джанго. Фальшивый Https есть, работает через django-extension и Werkzeug. Подключал все через python-social-auth. При попытке авторизации на фейсбуке, постоянно выскакивает ошибка:

> URL заблокирован: Не удалось выполнить переадресацию, поскольку конечный URI не внесен в «белый» список в разделе приложения «Клиентские настройки OAuth». Убедитесь в том, что вход с помощью OAuth включен для клиента и веб-форм, а также добавьте все домены вашего приложения в качестве действительных URI для переадресации OAuth.

Ниже настройки самого приложения на фейсбуке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее мой settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os 


SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://mysite.com:8000/facebook/callback/'
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'as#n87m6=357!n5=2_gc@$#a48_73(k-7_#o6!%6r#&i9r^f-l'


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com', '127.0.0.1']
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ################################ +
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'django_extensions',
    ################################
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'register_syte.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'register_syte.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '1152120558615350'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '0fe1ec5e38e1d4c2066f230a3cfa1d9d'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',)

########### FACEBOOK AUTH DETAILS ##########################



# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Понятия не имею, что может быть не так. Если вам будут необходимы дополнительные данные - напишите.

Comment: Ошибка случано не на локалке происходит?

Comment: да, но локальный сервер с https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, проблема решилась с переходом на библиотеку django-allauth, в которой явным образом прописаны все callback ссылки. Также помог переход на django-sslserver вместо Werkzeug, для фальшивого https. Никому не советую пользоваться  python-social-auth. Работать может, но с django-allauth гораздо быстрее, удобнее и доки по приличнее. [Эта статья](https://jinkwon711.medium.com/django-allauth-facebook-login-b536444cbc6b) неплохо помогла, в рунете по этой теме все давно устарело.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать [данную](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) библиотеку, чтобы подключить авторизацию через Facebook, используя токены.